# Display count of new members registered today

Tags: buddypress, count, members

I would like to display the registered members count for today in BuddyPress. Something like:

**20** new members registered today

I have no clue where to start, so I cannot provide any code yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function bp_registrations_today($activated = false) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE DATE(user_registered) = CURDATE()";

    if ( $activated ) {
        $query .= " AND user_status = 0";
    }

    return $wpdb->get_var($query);
}
```

To get the number of users registered today, call the function as

```
echo bp_registrations_today();
```

To get the number of users registered today with activated accounts, call the function as

```
echo bp_registrations_today(true);
```

Comment: Thank You Chittaranjan, will check it out tonight and will write here the result !!

Comment: It is working perfectly Chittaranjan !! Thank you very much